# How do I remove the Show/Hide links on a subgroup in ActiveScaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activescaffold

With ActiveScaffold I have a group on my create form:

```
config.create.columns.add_subgroup "Customer" do |customer_group|
  customer_group.add :customer_surname, :customer_postcode
end
```

This has a Show/Hide link which I don't want. **How do I remove the Show/Hide links on a subgroup in ActiveScaffold?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting for that (at the time of writing). You have to patch it yourself.

The code is in the helper method `link_to_visibility_toggle` in the file `lib/active_scaffold/helpers/view_helpers.rb` of Active Scaffold.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a css rule like:

```
a.visibility-toggle { display: none; }
```

You'll probably want to scope the css selector more finely to only hide the specific sub-group toggles.